# Lottie for Flutter shows wrong animation

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this animation from Adobe After Effects:

[image]

But flutter displays it like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
                child: Lottie.asset(
                  'lib/assets/data.json',
                  repeat: false,
                  reverse: false,
                  animate: false,
                  controller: _controller,
                  onLoaded: (composition) {
                    _controller
                      ..duration = composition.duration
                      ..reset();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: This is not caused by flutter it seems your animations were not well configured/masked go through the requirements for a perfect lottie file animations on their site

Comment: @Davis, It seems to me that these are still problems with flutter, since this animation is shown correctly everywhere, except for flutter